# Setup wireless repeater without additional ip address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, setup, repeater

I work in a building, where the whole building is connected via wireless. There are more than one access points. The place where I sit has poor signal. The authority has agreed to allow me put a repeater without disturbing the existing network. I looked around and found both repeater and extenders. But it seems in both the ways the new device requires an extra ip address. I was also thinking of sharing the improved network with my colleagues. We need to login to the company server to access internet, which uses an ip based login scheme. It seems that in both repeater and extender, the base router will only be able to see one ip address, which I don't want. I just want that the repeater will boost the signal coming from the existing access points and also send the boost up signals from our laptops. Is there any way to configure a repeater or extender in such way? Or are there any such device? Note that I cannot plug in the new device using ethernet to the central LAN. A few suggestions about which company would be better will be helpful (the base router is of Linksys).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [TP-Link](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WA901ND) or [This model](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WA701ND), for quiet some time now in various places, without problem. You need to connect them to a laptop via Ethernet and configure it (details available on site), and your jobs is done.